# Ajax Image Upload - Get tmpname

Tags: javascript, php

Iam trying to create Ajax-Image Upload. Inorder to move image using `move_uploaded_file()` i need the `name` and `tmp_name`. 
Is there any functions in javascript to get the filename and temporary file name like the following on php.

```
$n=$_FILES["filefield"]["name"];
$t=$_FILES["filefield"]["tmp_name"];
```

I have the image name on the variable `$newTidImg[1]`. Can i assign like following

```
$n=$_FILES[$newTidImg[1]]["name"];
$t=$_FILES[$newTidImg[1]]["tmp_name"];
```

The following function used for ajax post which passes id and image name to `changeImageAjx.php`

`function ajximgupls(trid,imgnam)`

```
var tridImgval = trid+','+imgnam;
jQuery.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'changeImageAjx.php',
data: 'urlTidimgs='+ tridImgval,
cache: false,
success: function(ret)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot handle the image from javascript. but you can send the image back to javascript from php. $_FILES["filefield"]["tmp_name"] is the temp path of the file its a local file uri. you cannot do anything using javascript.

you can use 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filefield"]["tmp_name"],"local file path");

only from php side not from javascript.